# Flutter nested StreamBuilders causing Bad state: Stream has already been listened to

Tags: architecture, dart, flutter

I'm trying to build a Flutter app using the BLoC pattern described in the video [Flutter / AngularDart – Code sharing, better together (DartConf 2018)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLHln7wHgPE&feature=youtu.be)

A BLoC is basically a view model with `Sink` inputs and `Stream` outputs. In my example it looks a bit like this:

```
 class BLoC {
    // inputs
    Sink<String> inputTextChanges;
    Sink<Null> submitButtonClicks;

    // outputs
    Stream<bool> showLoading;
    Stream<bool> submitEnabled;
 }
```

I have the BLoC defined in a widget near the root of the hierarchy and it is passed down to widgets beneath it, including nested `StreamBuilders`. Like so:

[image: BLoC widget hierarchy]

The top `StreamBuilder` listens to a `showLoading` stream on the BLoC so that it can rebuild to show an overlaid progress spinner. The bottom `StreamBuilder` listens to a `submitEnabled` stream to enable/disable a button.

The problem is whenever the `showLoading` stream causes the top `StreamBuilder` to rebuild the widget it rebuilds nested widgets too. This in itself is fine and expected. However this results in the bottom `StreamBuilder` being recreated. When this happens it attempts to re-subscribe to the existing `submitEnabled` stream on the BLoC causing `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to`

Is there any way to accomplish this without making all of the outputs `BroadcastStreams`?

(There is also a chance that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the BLoC pattern.)

---

Actual code example below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(BlocExampleApp());

class BlocExampleApp extends StatefulWidget {

  BlocExampleApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BlocExampleAppState createState() => _BlocExampleAppState();
}

class _BlocExampleAppState extends State<BlocExampleApp> {

  Bloc bloc = Bloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(elevation: 0.0),
            body: new StreamBuilder<bool>(
                stream: bloc.showLoading,
                builder: (context, snapshot) =>
                snapshot.data
                    ? _overlayLoadingWidget(_buildContent(context))
                    : _buildContent(context)
            )
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildContent(context) =>
      Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              onChanged: bloc.inputTextChanges.add,
            ),
            StreamBuilder<bool>(
                stream: bloc.submitEnabled,
                builder: ((context, snapshot) =>
                    MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: snapshot.data ? () => bloc.submitClicks.add(null) : null,
                      child: Text('Submit'),
                    )
                )
            )
          ]
      );

  Widget _overlayLoadingWidget(Widget content) =>
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          content,
          Container(
            color: Colors.black54,
          ),
          Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ],
      );
}

class Bloc {
  final StreamController<String> _inputTextChanges = StreamController<String>();
  final StreamController<Null> _submitClicks = StreamController();

  // Inputs
  Sink<String> get inputTextChanges => _inputTextChanges.sink;

  Sink<Null> get submitClicks => _submitClicks.sink;

  // Outputs
  Stream<bool> get submitEnabled =>
      Observable<String>(_inputTextChanges.stream)
          .distinct()
          .map(_isInputValid);

  Stream<bool> get showLoading => _submitClicks.stream.map((_) => true);

  bool _isInputValid(String input) => true;

  void dispose() {
    _inputTextChanges.close();
    _submitClicks.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: using multiple streams for a single event source is not right, just use a broadcast stream

Comment: Conceptually there aren't multiple observers to each source. The fact that the same observer is rebuilt and needs to re-subscribe is a Flutter implementation detail. This may not happen if the UI was built with something like Angular. But say all outputs were made broadcast streams on the chance that they _may_ have multiple observers, are there any side effects? Do StreamBuilders unsubscribe to their streams when they're destroyed and rebuilt?

Comment: This might be of help https://youtu.be/RS36gBEp8OI?t=20m30s

Comment: Looks like your question could be "is it possible to pass multiple streams to StreamBuilder?". The problem is that your example is very simple. I can't understand what to do if I need to listen more than two streams, for example I want to listen to the network state of the request, errors and the result object. I think it should be something like `stream: [bloc.isLoading, bloc.errors, bloc.user]`. Because the nested wrapping by `StreamBuilder` of widgets is looking very messy.

Answer (score 3):

As i understand BLoC you should only have one output stream which is connected to a StreamBuilder. This output stream emits a model which contains all required state.

You can see how its done here: <strike>https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/blob/master/example/flutter/github_search/lib/github_search_widget.dart</strike>

**New Link:**
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/blob/master/example/flutter/github_search/lib/search_widget.dart

If you need to combine multiple steams to generate you model (sowLoading and submitEnabled), you can use `Observable.combineLatest` from RxDart to merge multiple streams into one stream. I use this approach and it works really nice.

Comment: I did have a look at that example, and it's great, however it's different to the pattern described in the video in that it does only have a single output stream containing the entire state model. The BLoC pattern in the video has multiple output streams that are independently subscribable, which is what I like about it. Otherwise I'd probably use something like redux

Comment: The urls is no longer available, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

use BehaviorSubject instead StreamController.BehaviorSubject will send the nearest event to the consumer